# Update user to avoid duplicate (devise+omniauth:twitter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I created a rails app where users were able to signed up with devise ! But I just added omniauth-twitter - So now users can signed up with Twitter.
The problem is that some users already has their email adresses in the DB, so when they logged in using twitter, they are redirected to the final registration step, where they are supposed to add their email adress (because twitter doesn't give you the email adresses of their users).

What is the best way to deal with this concern ?

Should I reset my DB? so users will have to create a new account from scratch ? (easy steps with the twitter login) 
Or is there a way to update the DB to allow duplicate of email for users who are already in the DB?

if someone can help me with this,  I would highly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best guide out there for that. It worked for me.
http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/#comment-198